# can't display a simple graph using jqplot

Tags: javascript, html, graph, jqplot

I'm a new employee at a company and also new to php and jqplot. :$
    I'm trying to create a simple graph using jqplot. 
    I followed all the instructions at http://www.jqplot.com/tests/line-charts.php 
    but nothing is displayed in my div :(
    can someone help?
I think the problem might that its not loading the jqplot files :,(

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <title>Capacity Report</title>
        <!--[if lt IE 9]><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../../../jqplot/excanvas.js"></script><![endif]-->


                <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
                <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery.jqplot.min.js"></script>
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.jqplot.css"/>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../css/style.css" type="text/css"/>
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../../jqplot/jquery.jqplot.css"/>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery.jqplot.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.jqplot.com/src/jquery.jqplot.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="../../../jqplot/jquery.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="../../../jqplot/jquery.jqplot.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqplot/plugins/jqplot.canvasTextRenderer.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqplot/plugins/jqplot.canvasAxisLabelRenderer.js"></script>
               <script type="text/javascript" src="../../../jqplot/plugins/jqplot.ohlcRenderer.js"></script>
               <script type="text/javascript" src="../../../jqplot/plugins/jqplot.highlighter.js"></script>
               <script type="text/javascript" src="../../../jqplot/plugins/jqplot.dateAxisRenderer.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="../../../jqplot/plugins/jqplot.canvasAxisTickRenderer.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="../../../jqplot/plugins/jqplot.trendline.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>

               <div id="chartdiv" style="height:400px;width:300px; ">graph1</div>
               <div id="chart1" style="height:400px;width:300px; ">graph2</div>
</body>
</html>

<script>  $.jqplot('chartdiv',  [[[1, 2],[3,5.12],[5,13.1],[7,33.6],[9,85.9],[11,219.9]]]); 
$(document).ready(function(){
        console.log("It works!!!");
        var plot1 = $.jqplot ('chart1', [[3,7,9,1,4,6,8,2,5]]);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I even found this other super simple link to display a graph: http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/usage-txt.html .... but it doesnt work

Comment: This is very strange!
once I create this same test in the jqplot file, it displays the graphs!!!! so it is a problem with my file path :p ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello everyone i solved my error!
the problem was in the file path! after many hours of playing around i realized i was trying to open jqplot file with a wrong path!!! :P
hope this will help someone else with the same problem
this is my final working code 100% bullet proof :)

```
<html>

<head>
<title>Working plots functions</title>

<!--[if lt IE 9]><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="excanvas.js"></script><![endif]-->
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../../jqplot/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../../jqplot/jquery.jqplot.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
        console.log("It works!!!");
        var plot1 = $.jqplot ('chart1', [[3,7,9,1,4,6,8,2,5]]);
    });

$(document).ready(function(){
        console.log("It works!!!");
        var plot1 = $.jqplot ('chart2', [[3,7,9,1,5,6,8,2,5]]);
    });
</script>
Here is the start of the page...<br>

<div id="chart1" style="height:400px;width:300px;">graph1</div>
<div id="chart2" style="height:400px;width:300px;">graph2</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: if it doesnt display a graph, means your path is not right ;)
have fun playing with it.